# ASP.NET Catch all routing and escaping forward slashes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using catch-all routing with MVC to provide a path to a resource in our application.  It looks like such:

```
_routes.MapRoute(null, "Resource/{*resourcePath}", new { 
    controller = "Resource", 
    action = "Open" 
});
```

And the action is something like

```
public ActionResult Open(string resourcePath) {
    string[] path = resourcePath.Split('/');
}
```

Hitting it with a nice and friendly URL it works fine

```
/Resource/Path/To/Resource  
    path = ["Path", "To", "Resource"]
```

But when I have a resource name with a forward slash in it (which I, of course, escape), it treats the escaped slash as part of the path

```
/Resource/Path/To/Resource%2FWith%2FSlashes  
    path = ["Path", "To", "Resource", "With", "Slashes"]
    I expected ["Path", "To", "Resource/With/Slashes"]
```

I tried double escaping, only to have ASP.NET complain about double-escaping for security reasons, and I don't think I should open that can of worms.

Is there any way I can make the catch-all route not unescape the slash?

Comment: I guess you will have to use another encoding for forward slashes wich are not part of the path. For example use a double forwarding slash, then join split result parts which are separated by an empty element. Just random thoughts though...

Comment: I think IIS is one the decoding the URL

Comment: Looks like escaping by doubling doesn't work either, a URL with /Path/To/Resource//With//Doubled//Slashes gets changed to /Path/To/Resource/With/Doubled/Slashes by the time the request hits ASP.NET, but I think the idea will work with some other character