# How to pass catch-all (*) url parameter that contains a value of with `+` and `//` characters in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

My problem is very similar to: [ASP.NET Catch all routing and escaping forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698709/asp-net-catch-all-routing-and-escaping-forward-slashes), however that hasn't been answered for *over five* years.

I'm unable to "reconstruct" my `catch-all` URL segment in ASP.NET Core when there are multiple `/` and `+` characters (encoded) contained within.

When I create an API controller with a route like this:

```
[Route("path/{*catchAll}")]
public string Path(string catchAll = null) {
    return catchAll;
}
```

First, .NET Core rejects a URL like this: `/path/double%2F%2Fslash%2Bplus` because of **double escaping** for which I add the following to a web.config.

```
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
```

However, the value returned for a URL like this: `/path/double%2F%2Fslash%2Bplus` outputs this:

> double/slash+plus

Actually, no matter how many `%2F` *instances* are in the URL, they are all merged to a single `/`.

Now when I actually **double escape** the value like `double%252F%252Fslash%252Bcomment` it *single parses* the `/` characters while *double parsing* the `+` characters... Outputting:

> double%2F%2Fslash+comment

However I cannot just decode this again because this will yield:

> double//slash comment

missing the `+` characters...

**Is there a way in a controller in ASP.NET Core to get/reconstruct the value with both `//` included together with my `+` characters??**

Comment: Haven't tried it, but maybe this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256942/1220550

Comment: @PeterB: just tried, but the urls are already changed before they get to the middleware so this doesn't work.

Comment: I had this issue. I believe IIS merges the double slashes into one. There is nothing that can be done. I tried looking at all fields of `Request` and at all server variables etc.. Maybe a host different from IIS does not do this.

Comment: @usr - hmm when I run the project as console application, starting the project with Kestrel instead of IIS/IIS Express it does seem to work correctly... Is there no way to get around this at the IIS/configuration level?